# Regex for this rule

Tags: regex

How do I create a regular expression for this rule?

I should only accept this number if these rules are followed.

Starts with 03 or 04, 10 digits long

Starts with 3 or 4, 9 digits long

Edit:

So far, I have only this.

```
/^[0-9]{9,10}$/
```

It can only accept numbers with 9 or 10 digits. The starting digits however are still from 0 to 9. It should only be specific, 3 or 4 for 9 digit number, 03 or 04 for 10 digit number. The rule should be one line, applicable to both rules.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your code?

Comment: This one is trivial enough that you should have tried by yourself in the first place. Show us your efforts and we'll see what's wrong with it.

Comment: 6 and 7 or 3 and 4, which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
/^0?[34][0-9]{8}$/
```

Comment: You can make it `^0?[34][0-9]{8}$` without the `|` or else it could also match a pipe char.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below regex:

`^(03|04)[1-9]{8}$` -> for Starting by 03 or 04 , 10 digits long

[Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/qhOWDx/1)

`/^(3|4)[0-9]{8}$/gm` -> Starting by 3 or 4 , 9 digits long

[Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/9pXWfZ/1)